# Angularjs: Element based directive communication

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have the need to have two Element Based directives.

The both have their own UI hence why I used restrict: "E"

I need a way to pass data from one/or more directives to another

The two directives sending data are in two different controllers (one in the page head, and one in the page body) therefore attempting to use

```
scope: {
    onNotify : "&"
}
```

just becomes messy since the scopes are different.

The best I could come up with is a "message bus" pattern. Where I have introduced a 3rd (attributed based) directive that exposes an "api"

```
api = {
  addListener : function(event, fn),
  publish : function(event, data)
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/concept/dELCv/

My questions are these:

1. Is this in-fact the only way to get two element-based directives to communicate?
2. The scope feels wrong, since i have had to use $(document).data("fc-bus.api", api) to share the api instance between controllers. Can someone please suggest a better way of sharing the API between the controllers

It works and I guess it is fine, however it really doesn't feel very "angular" with the global scoped api

I look forward to all your answers and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the 3rd directive, create a service to share the data and `$watch` for changes on the service's data inside of each directive.